# two figures inside text css

Tags: html, css

I'm new to css and I'd like to replicate [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VN3lv.png) that has two figures with two colors inside, also carries a text inside

I'm using a framework called Specter.css for the grids, I've done the following in the html file:

```
   <div class="container pt-50">
    <div class="columns">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-mx-auto">
            <p class="text-center pt-10 pb-10 pl-40 pr-40 grad rounded">Lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my css:

```
.pt-10{ padding-top: 10px;}
.pb-10{ padding-bottom: 10px;}
.pl-10{ padding-left: 40px;}
.pr-40{ padding-right: 40px; }

.grad {
background-image: linear-gradient(-90deg, #FACE84,#D47465); 
}

.rounded{
border-radius: 25px;
}
```

And I got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tr6OM.png)

As you can see I made a gradient but I do not know what else to do to get the figure that I mentioned

I appreciate the help you can give me

Comment: Replicate as a background or what?

Comment: No, its just a padding with text

Comment: @Xdark use svg .

Comment: You need to be clearer with your question. What is it you're exactly trying to do, what have you done already?

Comment: @swonder Yes, I'm sorry, I already edited the question

Comment: Svg all the way

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading though the attached link. it takes you through how to make a ying yang which is similar to this. Hope this helps.

https://css-tricks.com/creating-yin-yang-loaders-web/